# PostgreSQL - Recursive CTE Self-Join for Manager Hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm having trouble putting together a recursive query in PostgreSQL to show management hierarchy across employees. In order to achieve this, I would need to self-join the table to itself until every employee reached the end of their hierarchy. My data looks like this on a given day:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|    date    | employee_id | terminated_flag | manager_employee_id |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2019-01-31 |           3 |               0 |                   2 |
| 2019-01-31 |           2 |               1 |                   1 |
| 2019-01-31 |           1 |               0 |                     |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Ideally, I would like to create a JSONB column that contains the full hierarchy and manager details for a given employee. I know I can append to an existing JSONB column through recursion, but getting to that point has been the struggle. The desired output would look like this (removing columns for ease of readability):

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    date    | employee_id |                     manager_hierarchy                     |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-01-31 |           3 | {{"level":1,"id":2,"term":1},{"level":2,"id":1,"term":0}} |
| 2019-01-31 |           2 | {{"level":1,"id":1,"term":0}}                             |
| 2019-01-31 |           1 |                                                           |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my dataset, there could be N levels away from any given employee to the CEO, so the recursion would need to end once every employee had reached the CEO, who would have a NULL value for manager_employee_id.

Is this possible? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would view this as a recursive CTE to get the hierarchy and then aggregation to create the jsonb value:

```
with recursive t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (3, 2, 0), (2, 1, 1), (1, null, 0)) v(employee_id, manager_employee_id, terminated_flag)
     ),
     cte as (
      select distinct employee_id, manager_employee_id, terminated_flag, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select cte.employee_id, t.manager_employee_id, t.terminated_flag, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.manager_employee_id = t.employee_id
     )
select employee_id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('level', lev, 'id', manager_employee_id, 'terminated_flag', terminated_flag))
from cte
group by employee_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3ff7283817c8d0c133f3eecbaf454796) is a db<>fiddle.